# Отображение зависимости одного параметра относительно всех остальных при помощи `pairplot`

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, визуализация, seaborn

У меня таблица из 82 параметров. Отобразил зависимости между первыми пятью. А мне нужно отобразить зависимости одного параметра относительно всех остальных, т.е. столбец таких гистограмм:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
sns.pairplot(dataset.iloc[:,0:5])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [параметрами `{x, y}_vars`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html).

Пример:

```
d = pd.read_csv(r"D:\work\ML\titanic\train.csv")
data = d.select_dtypes("number").drop(columns=["PassengerId"])

sns.pairplot(data=data, y_vars=["Age"], x_vars=data.columns.drop("Age"))
```

---

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]